# Is my implementation of multiple class inheritance correct?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a question about multiple class inheritance in python. I think that I have already implemented it correctly, however it is somehow not in line with my usual understanding of inheritance (the usage of super(), specifically) and I am not really sure whether this could lead to errors or certain attributes not be updated etc.

So, let me try to describe the basic problem clearly:

- I have three classes Base, First and Second
- Both First and Second need to inherit from Base
- Second also inherits from First
- Base is an external module that has certain base methods needed for First and Second to function correctly
- First is a base class for Second, which contains methods that I would have to repetitively write down in Second
- Second is the actual class that I use. It implements additional methods and attributes. Second is a class for which the design may vary a lot, so I want to flexibly change it without having all the code from first written in Second.
- The most important point about Second however is the following: As visible below, in Second's init, I firstly want to inherit from Base and perform some operations that require methods from Base. Then, after that, I would like to launch the operations in the init of First, which manipulate some of the parameters that are instantiated in Second. For that, I inherit from First at the end of Second's init-body.
- You can see how the variable a is manipulated by throughout the initialization of Second. The current behavior is as I wish, but the structure of my code looks somehow weird, which is why I am asking.
- Why the hell do I want to do this? Think of the First class having many methods and also performing many operations (on parameters from Second) in it's init body. I don't want to have all these methods in the body of Second and all these operations in the init of Second (here the parameter a). First is a class that will rarely change, so it is better for clarity and compactness to move it back to another file, at least in my opinion ^^. Also, due to the sequence of calls in Second's init, I did not find another way to realize it.

Now the code:

```py
class Base():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def base_method1(self):
        print('Base Method 1')
        pass
    
    def base_method2(self):
        pass
    
    # ...

class First(Base): 
    
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        print('Add in Init')
        self.first_method1()
        
    def first_method1(self):
        self.a += 1.5
    
    def first_method2(self):
        pass
    
    # ...
        
class Second(First):
    
    def __init__(self,a):
        
        # set parameters
        self.a = a
        
        # inherit from Base class
        Base.__init__(self)
        
        # some operations that rely on Base-methods
        self.base_method1()
        
        print(self.a)
        
        # inherit from First and perform operations in First-init
        # that must follow AFTER the body of Second-init
        First.__init__(self)
        
        print(self.a)
    
        # checking whether Second has inherited the method(s) from First
        print('Add by calling method')
        self.first_method1()
        
        print(self.a)
        
sec = Second(0)
```

The output of the statement `sec = Second(0)` prints:

```py
Base Method 1
0
Add in Init
1.5
Add by calling method
3.0
```

I hope it is more or less clear; if not, I am glad to clarify!
Thanks, I appreciate any comment!

Best, JZ

Answer (score 0):

So - the basic problem here is that you are trying something for which multiple-inheritance is not a solution on itself - however there are ways to structure your code so that they work.

When using multiple-inheritance proper in Python, one should only have to call `super().method` *once* in each defined method, out of the base class, and only once, and do not call specific versions of the method by hardcoding an ancestor like you do in `Base.__init__()` on `Second` class. Just for start, with this design as is, `Base.__init__()` will run twice each time you instantiate `Second`.

The main problem in your assumptions lies in

> I firstly want to inherit from Base and perform some operations that require methods from Base. Then, after that, I would like to launch the operations in the init of First, which manipulate some of the parameters that are instantiated in Second. For that, I inherit from First at the end of Second's init-body.

So - if you call `super()`as you shall have perceived, no matter if you write `Second` as `class Second(Base, First)` , super will run the method in `First` *before* the method in Base. It happens because Python does linearize all ancestor classes when there is multiple-inheritance, so that there is always a predictable and deterministic order, in which each ancestor class shows up only once, to find attributes and call methods (the "mro" or "Method Resolution Order") - and the only possible way with your arrangement is to go Second->First->Base.

Now, if you really want to perform initialization of certain parts in `Base` prior to running intialization in `First`, that is where "more than multiple inheritance" comes into play: you have to define *slots* in your class - that is a design decision you do by yourself, and nothing ready-made on the language: agree on some convention of methods that `Base.__init__` will call at varying states of the initialization, so that they are activated at the proper time.

This way you could even skip having a `First.__init__` method - just have some method you know will be called on the child, by `Base.__init__` and override those as you need.

The language itself use this strategy when it offers both a `__new__` and a `__init__` method spec: each will run a different stage of initialization of a new instance.

Note that by doing it this way, you don't even need multiple inheritance for this case:

```
class Base():
    
    def __init__(self):
        # initial step
        self.base_method1()
        ...
        # first initalization step:
        self.init_1()
        #Intemediate common initialization
        ...
        # second initialization step
        ...

    def init_1(self):
        pass

    def init_2(self):
        pass

    def base_method1(self):
        pass

    # ...

class First(Base): 
    
    # __init__ actually uneeded here:
    #def __init__(self): 
    #    super().__init__()
    def init_1(self):
        print('Add in Init')
        self.first_method1()
        return super().init_1()
        
    # init_2 not used,
    def first_method1(self):
        self.a += 1.5
    
    def first_method2(self):
        pass
    
    # ...
        
class Second(First):
    
    def __init__(self,a):
        
        # set parameters
        self.a = a
        
        # some operations that rely on Base-methods
        super().__init__()  # will call Base.__init__ which should call "base_method1"
        
        # if you need access to self.a _before_  it is changed by First, you implement
        # the "init_1" slot  in this  "Second" class
            
        # At this point, the code in First that updates the attribute has already run
        
        print(self.a)


    def init_1(self):
        # this part of the code will be called by Base.__init__ 
        _before_  First.init_1 is executed:
        print("Initial value of self.a", a)
        # delegate to "init_1" stage on First:
        return super().init_1()
        
sec = Second(0)
```